# SQL Server date configuration error

Tags: sql-server

I  have a simple query:

```
select df_id 
from diasferiados 
where df_dia = '17/9/2017 5:20:03 PM'
```

I run it on PC #1 and works fine.

But when I try to run it on PC #2, I get this message:

> ERROR [22007] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I modify the date as follows (swap day and month):

```
'9/17/2017 5:20:03 PM'
```

It works fine on PC #2.

I can't modify my application so it must remain as the first case.

I'm guessing it's something about SQL Server Configuration but just can't find it.

Comment: Hi Donal, they're the same in both computers.

Comment: What client are you running this in? SSMS? An application? I only ever use ISO format _or_ use CONVERT to explicitly define the format. You're better off having code that will work on every PC rather than having to make config changes to every PC. This requires a change to your code.

Comment: It's running in a legacy application and is used on a limited number of PCs (6). Touching the legacy application is out of the question. We only got this error because of renewing one PC. On a second thought, this is the only Windows 10 all others are Windows 7, I'll take a look on that.

Comment: I don't know what Donal suggested (comment is deleted I think) but the first stop is regional settings etc.

Comment: If you can submit a SET DATEFORMAT upon connection it may fix it. Depending on your app there might be  way to do this without changing your app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to provide date&time as **string literals**, you learned yourself that most formats are **dependent on regional and language settings**.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

So in your concrete case, I'm pretty sure this query would work just fine on **both** your PC's:

```
select df_id 
from diasferiados 
where df_dia = '2017-09-17T17:20:03'
```

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Comment: Thank you marc_s, your answer helped me a lot. It's a tricky topic indeed.